# How to print out a hollow circle in c using just characters/symbols

Tags: c, math, terminal, geometry

Given the radius of the circle by the user, the program should print out the circle using the equation (x^2+y^2=r^2).

It works but I don't get something:

1. Why the points of the circle are so few, is there a way to make more points?
2. Why it looks more like an ellipse/oval?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void display(int r){
    int x,y;
    // x and y representing coordinates on an imaginary cartisian plane 
    for(x=-r;x<=r;x++)
    {  
        printf("\t\t\t");//some tabs to make it kinda "centered"
        for(y=-r;y<=r;y++)
        {
            /*if the coordinate:(x,y) is a point of the equation x^2+y^2=r^2 prints the char:*, if 
            not leaves that space empty*/
            if( x*x+y*y == r*r) 
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(){
    int r;
    printf("Enter radius:");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    display(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"each character of a circle"* - huh? Must have missed that geometry class...

Comment: (1) there can only be as many points as specified by `r`. (2) presumably because the characters in your terminal are higher than they are wide.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Is there a way to fix the first problem?

Comment: Hint: replace your condition with `if (x * x + y * y - r * r < 1)` and see what happens.

Comment: @ Jabberwocky I wanted to make a hollow circle, thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: `x * x + y * y == r * r` is only true when `x`, `y` and `r` describe the side lengths of a right-angled triangle.

Comment: You might wanna check out brasenham's circle rasterizing algorithm for that... [here you go](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*why the points of the circle are so few, is there a way to make more points?*

The reason is that you cannot represent the fractional part, you are handling integers and chars in a terminal. You could potentially multiply r by 4 (careful with overflow) and decrease the fontSize of your terminal to achieve this result.

*why it looks more like an ellipse/oval?*

Characters in terminal have higher height than width. The reason is to comfortably be able to read them and might also have to do with 16/9 resolution.

You could again have the desired ouput by adjusting your equation... but at this point you might want to just use a graphic library! Unless you are up to some ASCII art...

```
_____  // I used 4 dash horizontally and 3 vertically.
_   _
_____
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The condition `x*x + y*y == r*r` is only satisfied when `x`, `y` and `r` describe the side lengths of a right-angled triangle.  For integers, only "Pythagorean triples" such as 3,4,5 and 5,12,13, etc. satisfy that condition.

   More points can be plotted by allowing `x*x + y*y` to fall within a range centered about `r*r`, for example, between (*r*-½)² and (*r*+½)².

   Since (*r*-½)² = *r*²-*r*+¼, and (*r*+½)² = *r*²+*r*+¼, we can ignore the ¼ for simplicity and use the range `r*r-r` to `r*r+r`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void display(int r){
    int x,y;
    int xsq, ysq;
    int rsq = r*r;
    // x and y representing coordinates on an imaginary cartisian plane 
    for(x=-r;x<=r;x++)
    {  
        xsq = x*x;
        printf("\t\t\t");//some tabs to make it kinda "centered"
        for(y=-r;y<=r;y++)
        {
            /*if the coordinate:(x,y) is a point of the equation x^2+y^2=r^2 prints the char:*, if 
            not leaves that space empty*/
            int ysq = y*y;
            int dsq = xsq + ysq;
            if( dsq > rsq - r && dsq < rsq + r)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(){
    int r;
    printf("Enter radius:");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    display(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Input/output:

```
$ circle
Enter radius:10
                               *******
                             **       **
                            *           *
                           *             *
                          *               *
                         *                 *
                         *                 *
                        *                   *
                        *                   *
                        *                   *
                        *                   *
                        *                   *
                        *                   *
                        *                   *
                         *                 *
                         *                 *
                          *               *
                           *             *
                            *           *
                             **       **
                               *******
```

To account for the neglected ¼ from the expansion of (*r*-½)² and (*r*+½)², the condition could be changed from `dsq > rsq - r && dsq < rsq + r` to `dsq > rsq - r && dsq <= rsq + r`. That will change the output slightly for some radii.

2. The circle looks stretched because the font uses a non-square, rectangular grid.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the characters by default have aspect ratio 1:2 so to avoid having oval shape you have to print 2 characters per point.

And also to fill the gaps between the points you have to interpolate this gaps
here is a simple solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void display(int r)
{
    int x, y;
    // x and y representing coordinates on an imaginary cartisian plane
    for (x = -r; x <= r; x++)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t"); //some tabs to make it kinda "centered"
        for (y = -r; y <= r; y++)
        {
            if (abs(x * x + y * y - r * r) < r - 1)
                printf("**");
            else
                printf("--");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (x = -r; x <= r; x++)
    {
        printf("\t\t\t"); //some tabs to make it kinda "centered"
        for (y = -r; y <= r; y++)
        {
            printf("%s%d", (abs(x * x + y * y - r * r) > 10 ? " " : "  "), abs(x * x + y * y - r * r));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
    int r;
    printf("Enter radius:");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    display(r);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Enter radius:6
                                **********        
                              **          **      
                            **              **    
                          **                  **  
                        **                      **
                        **                      **
                        **                      **
                        **                      **
                        **                      **
                          **                  **  
                            **              **    
                              **          **      
                                **********
```